# Unable to fetch data: fetch is not defined => when defined, TypeError: fetch is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm creating a generator that uses your google catchall domain to generate a list of email accounts and how I'm going about it, is that a function will generate a random first & last name from an array and merges it together with the catchall domain. Essentially the result would be fname + lname + domain = johndoe@domain.com, but for some reason I'm getting an error. The terminal says "Fetch is not defined" but when I define it by either the node-fetch package (const fetch = require('node-fetch');, it then says "fetch is not a function". I was attempting to use the built in Fetch API to fetch the data because the script I'm basing it off of instructed to do so, after the terminal said it wasn't defined, I tried using the node-fetch package to define the variable fetch in hopes of it fixing it, but no luck either. Does anyone have a solution on why I'm getting both fetch is not a function and fetch is not defined?

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync") ({sigint: true });
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const request = require('request');
// const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const random_useragent = require('random-useragent');
const { Webhook, MessageBuilder } = require('discord-webhook-node');

const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

( async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false,
        executablePath: `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`,
        userDataDir: `/Users/bran_d0_n/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
        args: [
                `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`,
                `--enable-blink-feautres=IdleDetection`,
                `--window-size=1920,1080`,
                `--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process`, 
                `--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=true`
        ]
    });

    //------------------ Random Password Generator Function ------------------//

    function generatePassword() {

    let pass = '';
    let str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' + 
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$';

        for ( let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            var char = Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length + 1);
            pass += str.charAt(char)
        }
            return pass;
    }

    //------------------ First & Last Name Generator Function ------------------//
    
    async function fetchData(url) {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        return response.json();
    }

    async function fetchData(url) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network Response Invalid');
            }
            return response.json();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Unable To Fetch Data:', error)
        }
    }

    function fetchNames(nameType) {
        return fetchData(`https://www.randomlists.com/data/names-${nameType}.json`);
    }

    function pickRandom(list) {
        return list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
    }
   async function generateName(gender) {
        try {
            const response = await Promise.all ([
                fetchNames(gender || pickRandom(['male', 'female'])),
                fetchNames('surnames')
            ]);

            const [ firstNames, lastNames] = response;

            const firstName = pickRandom(firstNames.data);
            const lastName = pickRandom(lastNames.data);

            return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Unable To Generate Name:', error);
        }
    }

        console.log('Loading Browser...');



    // Account Values
        var bDayval = '01/05/22' + (Math.floor((Math.random() * ( 99-55 )) + 55 )).toString();
        var passwordVal = generatePassword();
        var fnameVal = generateName();
        var lnameVal = generateName();
        var info;
        var themessage;
        var phoneNum;
        var userpass;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loading and configuring the module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#user-content-loading-and-configuring-the-module)

> node-fetch from v3 is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with require().

> If you cannot switch to ESM, please use v2 which remains compatible with CommonJS. Critical bug fixes will continue to be published for v2.

You should either use

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

(Remember to add `"type": "module"` to the `package.json`)

Or install the older version

```
npm install node-fetch@2
```